# Kibana - Cannot output to log file

Tags: logging, debian, kibana

I have Kibana 6.7.1 installed on my debian server. I am unable to see logs.

What I did:

1. In the **/etc/kibana** directory I have configured **kibana.yml **  with **logging.dest: stdout**
2. Created the file /var/log/kibana.log
3. Changed permission of files with **chown 
   kibana:kibana kibana.log** and **chmod u+w kibana.log**.
4. Restarted the service with sudo service kibana restart

Still, I cannot see any content with the kibana.log file.

Any suggestions ?

After following fix suggestions I get error while starting kibana:

```
Dec 10 09:17:45 mynode systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Dec 10 09:17:45 mynode systemd[1]: kibana.service: Unit entered failed state.

Dec 10 09:17:45 mynode systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Dec 10 09:17:45 mynode systemd[1]: kibana.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

Dec 10 09:17:45 mynode systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.

Dec 10 09:17:45 mynode systemd[1]: kibana.service: Start request repeated too quickly.

Dec 10 09:17:45 mynode systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana.

Dec 10 09:17:45 mynode systemd[1]: kibana.service: Unit entered failed state.

Dec 10 09:17:45 mynode systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Is Kibana working fine?

Comment: posted above error after entering sudo service kibana status

Comment: Try installing the Kibana from scratch and start it (check if it logs content to log). Then update the question to clarify is it running in your case with default settings. Then change one thing and see is it still running also update the question and so on until you have problem and Kibana fails. Also use `systemctl status -l kibana` and you can change the output to be more verbose https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.7/settings.html see `logging.verbose:` setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by a combination of:

1. setting logging.dest in /etc/kibana/kibana.yml.
2. setting correct user permission to kibana.log (chown and chmod)
3. freeing up space in /var/log (space was full! found in journal)

Answer (score 2):

If you set `logging.dest` to `stdout`, it will output to the console, which will redirect to `/var/log/messages`, you need to set `logging.dest` to your file.

```
logging.dest: "/var/log/kibana.log"
```

Comment: Thanks. Corrected the line by inserting 

logging.dest: "/var/log/kibana.log" 

as suggested. I then restarted kibana by stop and start but it crashes after a while with error. I insert details in my original post.

Comment: Look in your messages log files, near the kibana error logs it should have the reason why kibana can't start.